# ReactJS - ReactiveSearch - Custom event on suggestion selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactivesearch

I am building an autocomplete component to search current users and add them to a team. The search works fine except I need to customize a couple things that I can't figure out how to do.

First, this component is modeled after GitHub's invite user modal. You can start typing to search for a current user and it populates any results it finds. However, if it doesn't find any results it only shows one item to invite that user via email. How can I edit the full state of the result list for a [DataSearch](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/search-components/datasearch.html) component? All I can see is to edit the content of each suggestion via the `onSuggestion` prop. I need to be able to say, "If there are zero results, display this."

Second, when a suggestion from the autocomplete result list is selected, I need to be able to reset the search box because I am populating a list that the user can see. Right now, the search box is populated with the value of the suggestion. So, I am populating the list below of selected results just fine; but, I still need to be able to reset the search box when that result is selected.

Help????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/oq4nyzr1mz)

For the first part of the problem, you can use the prop `onNoResults` on any of the results components to render custom JSX when no results are found. From the [docs](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/result-components/resultlist.html#props):

> **onNoResults** String or JSX [optional]
>
> show custom message or component when no results founds.

```
<ResultList
    ...
    // custom JSX when no results are found
    onNoResults={
        <section>
            <input />
            <button>Add</button>
        </section>
    }
/>
```

For the second part of the problem, there are two ways IMO you may approach this.

1. Using a [ReactiveComponent](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/advanced/reactivecomponent.html) which lets you create a custom ReactiveSearch component.
2. Using [customQuery](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/advanced/customquery.html)

I'll explain how to approach this using `customQuery` but it might be better to create a custom component depending on which approach suits your needs best.

In the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/oq4nyzr1mz) I've shared my [DataSearch](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/search-components/datasearch.html) looks like this:

```
<DataSearch
    title="DataSearch"
    dataField={["original_title", "original_title.search"]}
    categoryField="authors.raw"
    componentId="BookSensor"
    customQuery={this.customQuery}
    defaultSelected={this.state.value}
    onValueSelected={this.updateState}
/>
```

The reason for using a `customQuery` is to get full control of which query gets applied to retrieve the results. ReactiveSearch is designed to work [reactively](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/advanced/react.html). When a value is set into the `DataSearch`, the `ResultList` would react to this change. Having a `customQuery` lets us control which query is fired for this change. Also I'm keeping the value of `DataSearch` in the state so I can clear it up when the query gets fired. Here's what I'm using in the example:

```
customQuery = (value, props) => {
    // find the current query using defaultQuery from DataSearch
    const currentQuery = DataSearch.defaultQuery(value, props);
    // clear the value in component's state
    this.setState({
      value: ""
    });
    if (value.length) {
      // store this query
      this.prevQuery = currentQuery;
      return currentQuery;
    }
    // if the value is empty, that is it was cleared, return the previous query instead
    return this.prevQuery;
  };
```

So whenever the value is cleared, I just return the previous query so the result list shows the correct results for the previous query (before the value was cleared).

Also in order to control the value of `DataSearch` from my component I'm using the `defaultSelected` and `onValueSelected` props. They work quite similar to how you would create a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) in react. [Docs](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/search-components/datasearch.html#props)

Again, it might be better to create a custom component using [ReactiveComponent](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/advanced/reactivecomponent.html) if this approach sounds complicated to customize this flow.

[**Demo** for this answer using customQuery](https://codesandbox.io/s/oq4nyzr1mz)

Comment: Since I'm using the `DataSearch`, I never saw an option for `onNoResults` for DataSearch. Is that available for that component?

Comment: `onNoResults` is a prop for the result components, `ResultList`, `ResultCard` and `ReactiveList` all support this prop.

Comment: So, how could I accomplish the same with the DataSearch autocomplete? I need both of these to work with the DataSearch autocomplete component only since there is not a space on the page for a result list other than the DataSearch suggestion list.

Comment: Do you mean, you're not interested in showing the results but only the suggestions?

Comment: Correct. This is solely for the DataSearch suggestion dropdown list.

Comment: There is a proposal for adding a new prop `renderNoSuggestions` [here](https://github.com/appbaseio/reactivesearch/issues/438) which would be perfect for this usecase. Alternatively, you could use `ReactiveComponent`.

Comment: How would I use ReactiveComponent in this way?

Comment: The [docs](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/advanced/reactivecomponent.html) have a detailed explanation. That being said, the `renderNoSuggestions` prop would also be available in the next release shortly so you could wait for it.